# Displaying XML and XSL through AJAX

Tags: ajax, xml, xslt

I am trying to display my XML and XSL on a HTML page that is pulled through AJAX. I have got the XML pulling through to the HTML page but the XSL won't seem to display no matter what I do.

Here is my XML code:

```
<tv_guide>
<channel>
<channel_id> 1 </channel_id>

    <program> <!--beginning of channel1-->
        <title>News</title>
        <time>HELP</time>
        <duration_id>1</duration_id>
        <description>ABCD</description>
    </program>
</channel>
```

Here is my XSL code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method='html'/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="program">

    <td>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
    <xsl:value-of select="duration_id"/> </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
    <xsl:value-of select="duration"/>
     </xsl:attribute>
     <xsl:value-of select="name"/> </td>

    </xsl:for-each >

        </tr>



</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my AJAX code:

```
function loadXMLDocWed()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
    {
    document.getElementById("tabs-3").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","URL",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Any suggestions that you think may help will be greatly appreciated as I've been stuck on this for a while now.

Comment: It`s look like you missed a <tr> Tag on the xslt file ,
and </tv_guide>  on the xml file .

Comment: How are you applying the XSLT to the XML document? Does your XML document contain the `<?xml-stylesheet ` directive at the top, by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with the xslt script.
you tried to do for-each like that

```
<xsl:for-each select="program">
```

In xslt if you want to  get a nested element, **program** in your case you have tow options.

Recursively  "search" for the element  like that.

```
<xsl:for-each select="//program">
```

Full path like that.

```
<xsl:for-each select="tv_guide/channel/program">
```

you can find more references here [xslt](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp).

miki.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried to do it recursively and it displays the information in the table over and over again and it seems to be in the wrong order as well. I have also tried the full path and this doesn't seem to work at all, leaving me with only table headings. Is there any other way I would be able to do this? Many thanks.